# Windows security window not showing up when calling shortcut from bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, shortcuts

I have a shortcut on the desktop which links to a folder on a server. So when I double click it, a security window pops up asking me for my username and password as shown below

[image]

Now I am trying to call the shortcut from a bat file but the problem is that the security window doesn't appear and in the command line it says "Access Denied" although the bat file is run as administrator. I have to say that it works on some computers and others not but I don't know why? Any advice why it works normally from the desktop but not from the bat file?

Here is the bat file:

```
start "" "C:\Users\userA\Desktop\My-Server-folder.lnk"
```

Comment: Try adding .LNK to the PATHEXT environment variable and see if this helps.

Comment: `start "" "%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe" "C:\Users\userA\Desktop\My-Server-folder.lnk"` could help? Or simple `explorer.exe "C:\Users\userA\Desktop\My-Server-folder.lnk"`?

Comment: Set `C:\Users\userA\Desktop\My-Server-folder.lnk` to run as administrator?  Access denied is a permissions problem.

Comment: @JosefZ Now the Access denied message doesn't appear but still the security window doesn't pop up, any advice please?

Comment: Clear cached credentials? To do that: press the Windows key + R together to open the Run box. Type the `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` command and hit Enter.

Comment: @JosefZ I did that and it is empty.

Comment: @JosefZ Any advice please?